# Edit doesn't work in UI Component

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

```
<layout>
  <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
  <type>tabs</type>
</layout>
```

I have used the tab in form.xml but data not being populated within form while edit.

Comment: Can you add more information?

Comment: Thanks, I am using ui component for a custom module and put all form fields into two tabs, able to save the form data but edit is not working. It shows a blank form when I edit any stored record.

Comment: add your module here